# How to hide element after react-countdown-now time up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, show-hide, countdown

I'm trying to make a bidding website by ReactJs and here is the problem.
I hope the input form will hide after time countdown completed(npm react-countdown-now)

1.I try to setState True or False {this.state.showForm && } but it doesn't work after countdown completed and get error

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Countdown from 'react-countdown-now';

class Pricebidding extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props)
     this.state = {
       showForm: true,
     }
     this.renderer = this.renderer.bind(this);
  }

  renderer({ days, hours, minutes, seconds, completed}) {

    if (completed) {
        this.setState({ showForm: false })
        return <span>Time up</span>
    } else {
         this.setState({ showForm: true})   
        return 
        <span>{days}days{hours}hours{minutes}mins{seconds}secs</span>
    }
  }

  render()
     return (
        <div>
            <Countdown date={this.props.endtime} renderer={this.renderer}/>
            {this.state.showForm && <form>
                <input></input>
                <button type="submit">Bid</button>
                <span>{this.state.bidprompt}</span>
            </form> }
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Uncaught Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are getting an infinite loop because you are updating the state infinitely,

renderer -> setState -> renderer -> setState -> ...

you can fix the problem by rendering the `form` inside the `CountDown` component

```
class Pricebidding extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       bidprompt: '...'
     };
     this.renderer = this.renderer.bind(this);
   }

   renderer({ days, hours, minutes, seconds, completed}) {
    if (completed) {
       return <span>Time up</span>;
    } else {
      return (
       <>
          <span>{days}days{hours}hours{minutes}mins{seconds}secs</span>
          <form>
            <input></input>
            <button type="submit">Bid</button>
            <span>{this.state.bidprompt}</span>
         </form>
       </>
      );
    }
  }

  render()
    return (
        <Countdown 
           date={this.props.endtime} 
           renderer={this.renderer}
        />
    );
  }
}
```

if you want to keep a state in your component, you can use the  [onComplete property](https://github.com/ndresx/react-countdown#oncomplete)

```
class Pricebidding extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       showForm: true,
     };
     this.handleComplete = this.handleComplete.bind(this);
   }

   handleComplete() {
      this.setState({ showForm: false });
   }

   renderer({ days, hours, minutes, seconds, completed}) {
    if (completed) {
       return <span>Time up</span>;
    } else {
      return <span>{days}days{hours}hours{minutes}mins{seconds}secs</span>;
    }
  }

  render()
    return (
      <div>
        <Countdown 
           date={this.props.endtime} 
           renderer={this.renderer}
           onComplete={this.handleComplete}
         />
         {this.state.showForm && (
           <form>
             <input></input>
             <button type="submit">Bid</button>
             <span>{this.state.bidprompt}</span>
           </form> 
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Olivier thank you for helping me first method is work but when I try second one use onComplete to setState but it dosen't work.

Comment: Hi Olivier no error and I try to use console log to check why but I found my handleComplete function didn't fire

Comment: can you put a `console.log` in the `handleComplete` method to see if something is printed into the console

Comment: Yes I put it but the console.log didn't print so I think my onComplete function didn't work

Comment: this is weird, I created a sample app https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-countdown6 and its working perfectly. Are you using the last version of `react-countdown-now` ?

Comment: Hi Olivier, I think I found the problem because I pass the datetime is in the past...so maybe onComplete can't catch the time already past.When I set few seconds countdown ,the form will hide after time up but when I refresh the page the form will show again

Comment: so maybe you should init the state like this `this.state = {
       showForm: (new Date() > this.props.,endtime)
     };`

Comment: Hi Olivier, I try it but it will show the state all false

Comment: this is the expected behavior if `endTime` is passed no ?

Comment: Oh I think because my date type are different this is new Date() " Thu Aug 22 2019 21:37:31 GMT+0800 (台北標準時間)" type is Object and this is my datetime from my SQL "2019-08-21T16:00:00.000Z type is string
"

Comment: Hi Olivier It works great now "showForm: (new Date() < new Date(this.props.endtime)) "  thank you so much Olivier ! I'm appreciate